# ModX Ditto: Display selective documents

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution, ditto, modx-resources

I want to use Ditto to display a list of documents. I cannot seem to set this up to work correctly. So far I have:

```
[!Ditto? &amp;parents=`3` &amp;documents=`10,32,339,86,303,302` &amp;tpl=`blog_summary`!]
```

But this gives me all the items under Document 3.

Does anyone know the correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation `Documents: overrides parents property`. [Ditto docs](http://rtfm.modx.com/display/ADDON/Ditto+Parameters)

So your code should look like:

```
[!Ditto? &documents=`10,32,339,86,303,302` &tpl=`blog_summary`!]
```

PS: maximkou's might fail because parent 0 is considered the topelement of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a "parents" parameter to 0 or delete parameter "parents", documents exactly are childs of document with id=3?

Comment: Thanks but they are children of "3". Deleting it breaks Ditto and changing into 0 just adds more unwanted documents